# Impala vs SparkSQL: built-in function translation: fnv_hash

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, impala

I am using the `fnv_hash` in Impala to translate some string value into numbers. Now I am migrating to Spark SQL, is there a similar function in Spark SQL that I can use? An almost 1-1 function mapping string value to number should work. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately Spark doesn't provide direct replacement. While built-in `o.a.s.sql.functions.hash` / `pyspark.sql.functions.hash` uses MurmurHash 3, [which should have comparable properties with the same hash size](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/49550), Spark uses 32 bit hashes (compared to 64 bit `fnv_hash` in Impala). If this is acceptable just import `hash` and you're good to go:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import hash as hash_

df = sc.parallelize([("foo", ), ("bar", )]).toDF(["foo"])

df.select(hash_("foo"))
```

```
DataFrame[hash(foo): int]
```

If you need larger you can take a look at [`XXH64`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/39e2bad6a866d27c3ca594d15e574a1da3ee84cc/sql/catalyst/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/XXH64.java). It is not directly exposed using SQL functions, but the [Catalyst expression](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/47731e1865fa1e3a8881a1f4420017bdc026e455/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/hash.scala#L552) is public so all you need is a simple wrapper. Roughly something like this:

```scala
package com.example.spark.sql

import org.apache.spark.sql.Column
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.XxHash64

object functions {
  def xxhash64(cols: Column*): Column = new Column(
    new XxHash64(cols.map(_.expr))
  )
}
```

```py
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.column import Column, _to_java_column, _to_seq

def xxhash64(*cols):
    sc = SparkContext._active_spark_context
    jc = sc._jvm.com.example.spark.sql.functions.xxhash64(
        _to_seq(sc, cols, _to_java_column)
    )
    return Column(jc)

df.select(xxhash64("foo"))
```

```
DataFrame[xxHash(foo): bigint]
```